Check if argument is given in a function parameter
This question have a similar question here and here, too. I could have posted this as a comment but I don't have the privilege yet so I posted this. I have also found similar question with no answer that satisfy my requirements. I will do the codes do the further talking.
I c/c++ you can do like this:
void CallMe(int *p = NULL)
{
    if ( p!= NULL )
        *p = 0;
}

CallMe(); // Calling the function without arguments the function will do nothing. But...

int n;
CallMe(&n);
// Here, you are passing a pointer to your n that will be filled by the CallMe function.
For c/c++ programmer, you know what to expect on those two calls.

Now, I want to do it in PHP. And when I do my searching, the following are most popular methods that are suggested in the search result: isset, is_null and empty. I did my trial-and-error but nothing works like that c/c++ sample.
function CallMe(&$p=null)
{
    if ($p==null)
        return;

    if(!isset($p))
        return;

    if (is_null($p))
        return;

    if (empty($p))
        return;
    $p = time();
    return 'Argument was set to ' . $p;
}

CallMe();

On the first call where no argument is supplied, all argument evaluations will result to true and the function will do nothing. Let's try with an argument.
$a = 1;
CallMe($a);

Of source, the function will now make some sense out of that $a variable. But...
$a = null;
CallMe($a);

In this last call, the function will behave as if no argument is given.
Now, what I want to achieve is the function to be able to check (like the c/c++ sample) if an argument was supplied. Or, is there a way we could pass a pointer to a variable in PHP?

Sorry for not familiar with C / C++, but can you call CallMe(null) in it?

@KoalaYeung Calling CallMe(null) will be the same as CallMe().

It's fine if you're doing this for learning purposes, but if you're only after solving a specific problem you may get better answers by explaining your ultimate goal, and not just the attempted solution. Determining whether a function is called with arguments does not require pointers or references in PHP, and I'm not sure of what exact use case this falls short for.

@ÁlvaroGonzález I'm both learning and making a production and, although I posted a very simple code, I am actually creating a function that is part of a bigger production and I wish this PHP function could behave like the sample c++ function I posted above. And my question is not jus about if a function is called with or without arguments.

The main difference is C / C++ has a distinct pointer type, while PHP does not. From a function perspective, there is no way to distinguish if $p is:

NULL; or
a variable (e.g. $a) with a NULL value

There used to be run time pass-by-reference in PHP, but it was removed back in PHP 5. Which means the lack of reference / pointer type is probably a design choice of the language. And it's unlikely to change in the foreseeable future.
If you have multiple optional value, the closest thing I can think of is to use a value holder object instead of raw variable.
class Inter
{
        private int $i;

        public function set($val)
        {
                $this->i = $val;
                return $this;
        }

        public function get(): int
        {
                if (!isset($this->i)) {
                        throw new \Exception('No value is set');
                }
                return $this->i;
        }
}

function CallMe(?Inter $p=null, ?Inter $q=null) {
        if ($p !== null) {
                $p->set(time());
        }
        if ($q !== null) {
                $q->set(time());
        }
}

$a = new Inter();
$b = new Inter();
$b->set(1);
$c = new Inter();
CallMe(p: $a);
CallMe(q: $b);

var_dump($a->get());
var_dump($b->get());
var_dump($c->get());

In PHP, object instances are ALWAYS passed by reference. Hence there is no need to explicitly add a & to it.
Output:
int(1715219664)
int(1715219664)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No value is set in /home/foobar/test.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /home/foobar/test.php(40): Inter->get()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/foobar/test.php on line 16

This is not exactly what you asked for, but this is the closest I can think of.

I have already done that and it works. But making a bunch of loads it not ideal, I think. But, again, if PHP also supports implicit conversion like the c#'s static implicit operator (narrowing and widening of objects) this will make a life lots easier. But I have already accepted this one PHP limitation. This is a fact that not all you can do in one language can be done in different language. c/c++ & c# (with unsafe enabled) supports pointers but not PHP.

There is an old function you may call to check the number of function arguments that is actually supplied by user: func_num_args()
function CallMe(&$p=null)
{
    if (func_num_args() === 0)
    {
        // no argument supplied. do nothing.
        return;
    }
    $p = time();
    return 'Argument was set to ' . $p;
}

echo "Try supplying no argument:\n";
echo "---\n";
var_dump(CallMe());
echo "\n";

echo "Try supplying a variable with a value of null:\n";
echo "---\n";
$a = null;
var_dump($a);
var_dump(CallMe($a));
var_dump($a);

Output:
Try supplying no argument:
---
NULL

Try supplying a variable with a value of null:
---
NULL
string(30) "Argument was set to 1715217065"
int(1715217065)


func_num_args will only work if you have only one optional parameter in your function because you will know for sure which parameter was not given an argument. But functions with multiple optional parameters, func_num_args is useless as it can''t tell which parameters were given an argument and the ones that were not.

True. It works for the problem you posted, but not if you have multiple optional parameters.

The main difference is C / C++ has a distinct pointer type, while PHP does not. From a function perspective, there is no way to distinguish NULL from a variable with a NULL value.

So, I think there's no way a behavior like that could be achieved in PHP, right? And I just have to accept that. But I will leave my case open in case someone comes up with some crazy ideas.

No, I cannot think of a way to do it with scalar types. You may create a simple setter / getter object class / interface to achieve similar effect. But not if you want to do it directly on raw scalar variables.

If php only supports function overloading this will solve my problem.

You're right. But no, PHP doesn't support function overloading. And I think that's a design choice.
